# Is there a setting in Visual Studio 2008 to show keyboard shortcuts in button tooltips?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, tooltip

Visual Studio 6.0 used to show the keyboard shortcuts in the tooltips for the toolbar buttons. Is there a setting in Visual Studio 2008 that turns that on, or is that yet another case of Microsoft deciding to remove a feature that some find useful from one of their products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out:

[Did you know... you can show shortcut keys in toolbar tooltips? - #056](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2007/10/08/did-you-know-you-can-show-shortcut-keys-in-toolbar-tooltips.aspx)

> Right-click anywhere on any toolbar or
>   toolbar region to bring up the context
>   menu, and select Customize.  In the
>   lower left-hand corner, select Show
>   shortcut keys in ScreenTips.  Now when
>   you hover over a command, you'll see
>   the keyboard shortcut in the tooltip
>   (aka screen tip).

Sara Ford's blog is an excellent resource on Visual Studio.